# MYSQL query for finding value

Tags: java, mysql, sql

I need output in which if a person has donated blood, the last donated blood date would be entered in my DB. And what I want is when I select all records it should not display records of those donors who has donated blood within last 3 months. So Below is my query but I am not getting output as I want.

```
select id,name,date_format(dateee,'%d/%m/%Y') as datetwo 
from emp 
where dateee < curdate()-90;
```

Where "dateee" is my date column in database. And I am getting output as shown below.

```
OUTPUT:  
datetwo  
20/01/2015  
05/05/2015
```

See 2nd record. I should not get this because he has donated in last month only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this query

```
select id,name,date_format(dateee,'%d/%m/%Y') as datetwo 
from emp 
where dateee < (DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 3 MONTH));
```

Answer (score 0):

This query gives you the precise result, because it's used exact 90 days interval from the current date.

```
select id,name,date_format(dateee,'%d/%m/%Y') as datetwo 
from emp 
where dateee < DATE_SUB(curdate(), interval 90 day);
```

Comment: yeah it works too thanks alot sir :) but which one would be better one with months or one with day ?

Comment: You can't calculate 90 days in months measurement unit, can't you?

Comment: If you count days behind the current date rather than months because number of days in the month not always equal to 30.

Comment: yeah right. so can i take 92 days because of 31-30-31 sequence of days in a month. but if i take that way what should be done of february :D ?

Comment: Nop, in the question you have used 90 days.

Comment: Okay thanks alot @nikpon sir .all the concepts got cleared :) :D

Comment: No, don't accept this, my bad I didn't read the question carefully. You have asked to measure it in last 3 months.

Comment: yeah .considering february which one would be better then sir ?

Comment: `ineterval 3 month` this expression unit you should use if you count in months.